# How to Check for Intersecting Rects in An Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocos2d-iphone, intersection

How would I be able to detect a intersection of rects within an array? I am not entirely sure of the most efficient way to do this.
Thanks

Comment: Try the brute force algorithm (check each pair) first and optimize only if first approach is not efficient enough. The "most efficient way" depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Just use nested for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i<[array length]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<[array length] j++) {
        if (i!=j) {
            j = i+1;
            //Check for intersection between array[i] and array[j]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The inner loop should start with `j = i + 1`, otherwise each pair is checked twice.